# Using getexchangerates.com API to display table of prices in different currencies

Tags: api, jscript, rate

this is my first post here so please be gentle! :-)

I have a table of prices on a web page that is in GB Pounds and I'd like to add a few more columns with prices in a few major currencies (e.g. USD, EUR etc.)

I have found http://www.getexchangerates.com/api/ and can call the API but can't seem to get it to work from a web page. I understand this is to prevent cross site issues. Is there a way to do this, please?

If I can get the API call to work I should be able to get the calculations and table sorted.

The code I'm trying is below - it returns a blank page bar the Currencies heading.

```
<body>
<h1>Currencies</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.getexchangerates.com/api/latest.json?currencies=EUR,GBP";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
var out = "<table>";

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" + 
    arr[i].USD +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].EUR +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].GBP +
    "</td></tr>";
}
out += "</table>"
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
</html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Currencies</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>
<script>

(function() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://www.getexchangerates.com/api/latest.json?currencies=EUR,GBP";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var out = "<table border='1'><tr><td>USD</td><td>EUR</td><td>GBP</td></tr><tr><td>" + arr.USD + "</td><td>" + arr.EUR +"</td><td>" + arr.GBP + "</td></tr>" + "</table>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
})();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The data returned is an object and not an array. Hence you could not iterate through the data passed back.